# Uninstall Extension Magento 2 and Clean Database (tables and datas)

Tags: magento2

I need to uninstall an extension in Magento 2.3.1, this extension was installed manually. I follow the follow steps (for example for the extension "Size Chart"):

```
bin/magento module:disable Bss_SizeChart --clear-static-content
rm -rf app/code/Bss/SizeChart
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

But I have detected that there are still data and tables related to this extension in the database:

- In the table `eav_attribute` there is a record associated with this module (which I must delete manually so as not to have errors on my website
- In my database there is a table associated with this extension: `bss_size_chart`
- In the table `setup_module` there is a record associated with this extension

**My Questions**

- How can I know if there is more information associated with an extension that I want to delete?
- Is there any way to be able to uninstall an extension and automatically delete all the records and tables in my database associated with the extension we want to delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my undertsanding, the only way to clean it up automatically is if you have used composer to install it - you would then use composer to uninstall it.

If you check the `InstallSchema.php` or `UpgradeSchema` within the `Setup` folder it should at least shed some light of the tables / columns that were added, and you can then manually remove.